# C# Populate Database with data with 2 dates

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert

I am creating an Attendance Monitoring System and it can set leave, but only with one date, My desired output is I can set leave across two dates. For example from march 6 to march 9, it will insert into database leave with values march6,march 7, march8 and 9. Each date creates an added row

Here's my code:

```
private void setleave()
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TimeinTimeout](EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname, InDate, Remarks) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", textBox2.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
}
```

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

```
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"    SELECT EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname 
                                        FROM tblEmployee 
                                        WHERE EmployeeID = @1";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
            var fromDate = dateTimePickerFrom.Value;
            var toDate = dateTimePickerTo.Value;
            for(DateTime offDate = fromDate; offDate.Date <= toDate.Date; offDate = offDate.AddDays(1))
            {
              SetLeave(offDate);
            }
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to set Employee as Leave?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
                setleave();
                } 
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Employee ID!");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce another datepicker so the user can select `From` and `To` dates for leave.

Then you need to traverse the dates and call your method:

```
var fromDate = dateTimePickerFrom.Value;
var toDate = dateTimePickerTo.Value;
for(DateTime offDate = fromDate; offDate.Date <= toDate.Date; offDate = offDate.AddDays(1))
{
    SetLeave(offDate);
}
```

And make the following changes to your method:

```
private void Setleave(DateTime offDate)
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TimeinTimeout](EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname, InDate, Remarks) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);

    // This is the changed line
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", offDate.ToShortDateString());

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", textBox2.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
}
```

---

Try and use .NET naming conventions. I have changed your method name from `setLeave` to `SetLeave` to follow the convention of using Pascal case for method names.

Also, do validation to make sure the user does not choose an earlier date in the `To` datepicker than the value chosen in the `From` datepicker.

Comment: Where do I put the varfromdate and vartodate codes? I have Database validation embedded in the set leave button and calls the SetLeave() method, How do I do the validation where I make sure the user does not choose an earlier date in the To datepicker than the value chosen in the From datepicker? Forgive me, I'm just a novice C# programmer

Comment: put the `fromDate` etc. code in the button handler. You can put the code for validation in the button handler also.

Comment: Will this work?  
                                                                var timeSpan1 = dateTimePicker1.Value - dateTimePicker2.Value;
        if (Math.Abs(timeSpan1.TotalSeconds) > 1) {
            MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value + " is not same as " + dateTimePicker2.Value);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value + " is same as " + dateTimePicker2.Value);
        }

Comment: `if (dateTimePicker2.Value < dateTimePicker1.Value) { MessageBox.Show("from must be before to or whatever you want to show the user");}`. If the dates are the same that's ok. It will mean one day.

Comment: My code doesn't work where is the button handler? Is it the button1_Click? It doesnt work there

Comment: What does not work? please be more specific. are you getting an exception or a compile error?

Comment: Parameter @2 has no default value, As you can see Parameter @2 would come from the database inputted to the datagridview using select statement, my code works fine but after I added yours it just showed up I will send my code for time in. Refer to my answer

Comment: I edited my question refer to the below code for time in button

Comment: The if (dateTimePicker2.Value < dateTimePicker1.Value) { MessageBox.Show("from must be before to or whatever you want to show the user");} code has a bug if i press the button without cahnging the date it will execute meaning datwtimepicker 1 and datetimepicker2 is not equal, what now?